# Bind Collection to ListView, suppress duplicates of object but manipulate ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, .net-core

My problem, developing a shopping system on a Raspberry Pi 3 Bodel B, is as following:

First of all some context:

1. Raspberry Pi with Barcode Scanner is used as self-service shop

   - Employees scans a drink and the price on the screen is added up the price of the drink
   - Now a extension should be provided: A list of all currently scanned products should be shown.
2. Until now I only achieved, that every scanned product appears as one ListViewItem in the ListView

### This is my Model

```cs
    public partial class Product : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string DescriptionField;
    private System.DateTime ExpirationDateField;
    private int IDField;
    private string NameField;
    private decimal PriceField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Description {
        get {
            return this.DescriptionField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.DescriptionField, value) != true)) {
                this.DescriptionField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime ExpirationDate {
        get {
            return this.ExpirationDateField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.ExpirationDateField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.ExpirationDateField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ExpirationDate");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public int ID {
        get {
            return this.IDField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.IDField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.IDField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.NameField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.NameField, value) != true)) {
                this.NameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public decimal Price {
        get {
            return this.PriceField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.PriceField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.PriceField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Price");
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This model describes a product which can be bought in our shop.

### My XAML Snippet

```xml
<ListView Name="ProductSumUp" 
          AllowDrop="False"  
          SelectionMode="None" 
          CanDrag="False" 
          CanReorderItems="False" 
          CanDragItems="False" 
          Grid.Column="2" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="290" 
          Margin="10,10,0,0" 
          Grid.Row="1" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="180" 
          RenderTransformOrigin="1.682,0.59" 
          Foreground="White" 
          FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/Baskerville.ttf#Baskerville">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/Baskerville.ttf#Baskerville" 
                               Foreground="White">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Run x:Name="{Binding Price}"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Now my question is:

Is it possible, if a product was scanned twice, not to add a new `ListViewItem`, instead, the existing `ListViewItem` should be manipulated by adding the same Price on the existing Item.

I tried many possibilities and also asked some developers at my work but nobody could figure out.

If you need more information just ask.

Thanks in advance and excuse me for my horrible English grammar :)

Comment: you need an additional attribute like "count" that is initially set to 1 on new - then each time the same item needs to be added, you look if you arleady have it and increase the count attribute, otherwise you add a new item - so the "add" code needs to do this work

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but I bound the Collection in C# and am not adding items manually to the ListView

Comment: so how do the new scanned items get into the view?

Comment: Do two cans of Coke have the same `IDField`?

Comment: like I said before, I bound them programmatically

@JustinXL Yes they do

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "if a product was scanned twice, not to add a new ListViewItem, instead, the existing ListViewItem should be manipulated by adding the same Price on the existing Item." Can you elaborate?

Comment: Of course, I can show you the difference:
Current state:[Picture 1](http://i.imgur.com/kjIlFgP.jpg)
Wish state: [Picture 2](http://i.imgur.com/EPJRZ6s.jpg)

So you see, i dont want a second item of the same drink, but want the price of the drink added up on the products ListViewItem

Comment: Personally, I'd create a `ProductGroup` as the base item model for your `ListView`. Like @user230910 has already suggested, you will need a `Count` for this new class, you might also need a `TotalPrice` which basically is `Price` * `Count`. This is why most of the time we need a VM to extend our model class. In your case, the `ProductGroup` will act like a VM that helps fulfill UI needs.

Comment: @JustinXL exactly what i meant - nicely put :)

Comment: Okay now I understand, well explained.
I'll try my best and will respond here, if I found a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I worked out a solution by myself with nice support from @JustinXL and @user230910.

I'll just post my code here, so you can see that I came to a solution.

### XAML

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock 
             FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/Baskerville.ttf#Baskerville" 
             Foreground="White">
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=groupedProduct.Name}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding PriceSum,
                            Converter={StaticResource PriceConverter}, 
                            Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Count,
                            Converter={StaticResource StringFormatter},
                            ConverterParameter='Anzahl: {0}',
                            Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

---

### C# - Modelcode

```
public class ProductGroup : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void onPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private decimal _priceSum;
        private int _count;
        public Product groupedProduct { get; set; }
        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return _count;
            }
            set
            {
                _count = value;
                onPropertyChanged(this, "Count");
            }
        }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceSum
        {
            get { return _priceSum; }
            set
            {
                _priceSum = value;
                onPropertyChanged(this, "PriceSum");
            }
        }
    }
```

---

### C# - CollectionFill

```
ProductSumUp.ItemsSource = _showProducts;

bool prodExists = false;

foreach (ProductGroup prodz in _showProducts)
{
     if (prodz.groupedProduct.ID == prod.ID)
        {
          prodExists = true;
        }
}

if (!prodExists)
{
    ProductGroup prodGroup = new ProductGroup();
    prodGroup.groupedProduct = prod;
    prodGroup.Price = prod.Price;
    prodGroup.Count = 1;
    prodGroup.PriceSum += prod.Price;
    _showProducts.Add(prodGroup);
}
 else
{
    ProductGroup pgroup = _showProducts.First(x => x.groupedProduct.ID == prod.ID);

    if (pgroup != null)
    {
        pgroup.Count++;
        pgroup.PriceSum += pgroup.Price;
    }
}
```

---

[image: result]

Please don't judge my programming style, I solved the problem quick and dirty.

I hope that somebody could use my solution for his/her problems and thanks for your help, it saved me a lot of time.